# Let $Y=\frac{X^{2}}{2}$, Determine $F_{Y}(y)$

Tags: statistics, density-function

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGHPW.jpg

I have figured out that $F_{Y}(y)=1/8$ for $0<y<8$. The only problem is that shouldn't P(Y=2)=P(X=2)+P(X=-2). If i sub the values into their respective densities, they give unequal values. Why is this the case?

Comment: If $f_X(x) = x/8,$ for $0 < x < 4$ (and 0 elsewhere), as in the image, then $X$ is a _continuous_ random variable, and $P(X = 2) = P(X = -2) = 0.$  However, do you mean $F_Y(y) = 1/8$ or $f_Y(y) = 1/8,$ for $0 < y < 8?$ // @callculus (answer in progress): If the support of $X$ is $(0, 4)$, what is the support of $Y = X^2/2?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First of all it is the pdf $f_Y(y)$ rather than the cdf $F_Y(y)$. The
  complete pdf is

  $f_y(y)=\begin{cases} \frac18, \ \text{if} \ 0<y<8 \\ 0, \
     \text{elsewhere} \end{cases}$
- In general $P(X=x)=0$ if X is continuous.
- But $F_Y(2)=F_X(2)$. $F_X(-2)=0$ since the cdf of $X$ is

  $F_X(x)=\begin{cases} 0, \ \ \text{if} \ x<0 \\ \frac1{16}x^2, \ \text{if} \ 0\leq x\leq 4 \\ 1, \ \ \text{if} \ x>4 \end{cases}$

$F_X(2)=\frac1{16}\cdot 2^2=\frac14$

And the cdf of Y is

$F_Y(y)=\begin{cases} 0, \ \ \text{if} \ y<0 \\ \frac1{8}y, \ \text{if} \ 0\leq y\leq 8 \\ 1, \ \ \text{if} \ y>8 \end{cases}$

$F_Y(2)=\frac18\cdot 2=\frac14$

Comment: (*1) // "CDF method": $F_Y(t) = P(Y \le t) = P(X^2/2 \le t) = P(X \le \sqrt{2t}) = 2t/16 =  t/8,$ so $f_Y(t) = 1/8.$ All for $0 < t < 8.$